# Get specific text from a website (html)

Tags: c#, javascript, html, visual-studio, web

I want to make a small program so that I can listen to this radio station quick and easy.

http://www.offradio.gr/player

The problem is that I can't think of any way to get the nowplaying track name, the producer's name and the playing history.

I thought about extracting the specific data from the raw source code of the website, but the source code is like 4,000 lines of code - too much for me to handle.

Any thoughts?

I am using Visual Studio and C#

Comment: Do they not provide an API?

Comment: No. Not anything I know of. If everything else fails, I will try to contact them (and their developer) but I dont think they'll help me.

Comment: Maby you can handle it by using the WMP interface? They provide that I think

Comment: make an http call to url and parse the response to what you need

Comment: @colosso Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Yes I can make the http call. The qyestion is, how can I isolate the information I want out of 10 pages of information?

Comment: @user1924391 : what is the response format ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not the best way, but it is a starting point and it works:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted; // Subscribe event

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.offradio.gr/player"); // Navigate to radio stream
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    /*
    Look for the element containing the element with the track number
    I've chosen this one because it has an ID means it's always the same div
    */
    HtmlElement parent = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("show_info");

    if (parent != null) // This event fires multiple times. Sometimes this element hasn't been created yet
    {
        /*
        We know it's a childless node inside `#show_info`.
        So let's just search for it.
        */
        foreach (HtmlElement child in parent.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
        {
                if (child.Children.Count == 0) // Check if it has children
                {
                    string title = child.InnerText; // The result
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I had to use .NET functions, with JS I would go an easier way:

`document.querySelector('#show_info .field-content').innerText`

**UPDATE:**

Let me give you another hint.

Look at the output of `document.getElementById('show_info').innerText`.

You might parse it and you're done!

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I will try and I'll tell you how it went!